# How to show multiple images inside Linear Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an android video app where i will list screenshot images of every video atleast 10 pieces for each video.And i am using Linear Layout which is inside a nestedscrollview, to show those images but only works when i put 3 imageview but if i put more than 3 imageview then it doesn't work at all and the app doesn't respond.Here is my xml layout of the screenshot.xml file..

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1b" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1c" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1j" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1f" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1g" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1h" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/alaep1m" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely think about using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) here. 
Your app doesn't respond, beacause of memory issues.

Check the example: [Recycler View](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply but if you could give me an example of recyleview using my code?

Comment: I think it is really well documented in this example, that i provide for you. You just need to change the TextView to ImageView from the Adapter, and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to show the images. But for your simplicity.

Here is the code. but I would highly recommend going for either GridView or 
ListView or RecyclerView.

This is neither of them. But still, you can show it in your activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.yyy.MainActivity">

      <TableLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
           android:layout_height="380dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:weightSum="2">

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:id="@+id/imageOne"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"/>

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageTwo"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

           </TableRow>

           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:id="@+id/imageThree"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"/>

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageFour"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

           </TableRow>
           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:id="@+id/imageFive"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"/>

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageSix"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

           </TableRow>
           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:id="@+id/imageSeven"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"/>

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageEight"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

           </TableRow>
           <TableRow
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:id="@+id/imageNine"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"/>

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/imageTen"
                   android:scaleType="matrix"
                   android:background="@drawable/view_background"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

           </TableRow>

           </TableLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And yeah as I told you earlier there are still many ways to approach to your solution.